# Override stream operator behavior for units

Tags: c++, boost-units

Today I used `boost-units` for the first time and I was really satisfied with the outcome.

Unfortunately, I'm not completely satisfied with the display of the `operator<<` for a given unit.

The following code prints `m s^-2` on the console:

```
#include <boost/units/systems/si/acceleration.hpp>
#include <boost/units/io.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char**args) {
    using namespace boost::units;
    using namespace boost::units::si;

    std::cout << acceleration() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I'm wondering if there is an easy way to change the output to something like `m/(s^2)` or even `m/s^2`. I think, that this kind of representation might be easier to read.

Comment: Have you considered writing your own? That would give you total control over formatting.

Comment: The problem is that there may be ambiguities in the representation, particularly with fractional exponents. Formatting for `ostream` is probably only a good idea for logging or debugging purposes, and there it is just a matter of practice.